# Neo4J Cypher Complex Query

Tags: python, database, graph, neo4j, cypher

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtOwd.png) I have the following scenario in the image : red nodes are the topics , yellow nodes are the course names. I need to find the last topic that belongs to course CS201. In this example this should be the topic "Array". I cant turn this into cipher query language. I have tried :

```
MATCH (n:course)-[:isPartOf]->(x:label) where not x.name contains 'CS201' return n
```

This should give me the topic "Pointer" since it doesn't contain CS201 and then I thought I'd go one step back to reach topic "Array" However it does not work.

[image: graph image]

Comment: Base on your comment on my answer, I didn't get the problem, so can you explain more?

Comment: If I take the course CS201, I will first learn "List" then I will learn "Array" and then I will finish CS201 course.  If I want to learn CS204, I will first learn "Array" (because it is a topic that is both in CS201 and CS204) then I will learn Pointer and finish CS204. The problem is how will I know the last course of CS201 ? It is not Pointer because it is only part of CS204 so it should be topic Array.

Comment: I update my answer, but I can't test it, can you check it on your db? hope it help

Comment: Why are there multiple CS20[1-4] nodes? If you could consolidate the duplicate nodes, than you could just back-trace with something like `MATCH p=(c:Course)<-[*]-(t:Topic) RETURN c as course, t as topic, SIZE(NODES(p)) as priority`. Otherwise, defining 'last' in the cipher will be more difficult. (use @Tezra to notify me when you replay :3). Do you want the full list of topics for a class (and order)? Or given a class, what is the first topic you must learn? (Labels in this answer based on what the data is, not the actual data labels that are confusing =P)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up the direction and names.

```
MATCH (course:course)<-[:isPartOf]-(topic:label)<-[:hasPreq]-(prevTopic:label) 
where course.name contains 'CS201' 
return topic, prevTopic
```

Why do you have duplicate entries for the courses?
You probably didn't use MERGE on creation of the data.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt return me anything. Naming convention is not good but basically red nodes are topics (type course), yellow ones are courses and each red node = topic can be a part of multiple courses ( yellow ones). When a person wants to know the last topic of CS201 course, he should say that it is topic Array because after array, there is no topic that belongs to CS201 ( Pointer does not belong to CS201)

Answer (score 0):

**ON HOLD**

Use this cypher:

```
MATCH (c:course {name: 'CS201'})<-[:isPartOf]-(t:topic)
OPTIONAL MATCH path=((t)-[:next*]->(:topic)-[:isPartOf]->(c))
RETURN t, count(relationships(path)) AS count_rels
ORDER BY count_rels
```

but it will return array and pointer as `secondTopic`, like @Michael Hunger said in his answer you have duplicate `CS201` course, try unique constraints, [read docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-unique-nodes):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (course:course) ASSERT course.name IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns blank. Naming convention is not good but basically red nodes are topics (type course), yellow ones are courses and each red node = topic can be a part of multiple courses ( yellow ones). When a person wants to know the last topic of CS201 course, he should say that it is topic Array because after array, there is no topic that belongs to CS201 ( Pointer does not belong to CS201)